# Limits to the number of accounts?

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts

I wonder: is the built-in accounts facility scalable enough that you can assign each newly minted address to a different account?  Or am I going to run into hard limits, or a database that becomes too sluggish because accounts were meant to be few in number?

Comment: The upcoming switch to LevelDB and/or the implementation of Ultraprune will likely eliminate any problem, if one exists.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

There most likely isn't any hard limit - you might only be limited by your computer's memory (and even then, that would require tons of addresses).